# Vim + tailwind incrementing numbers

Tags: vim, tailwind-css

When using tailwind, there are many utility classes like px-1, py-1 etc. When using Ctrl+a to increment px-1, it becomes px0. How can I make Ctrl+a on px-1 become px-2 instead?

Answer (score 1):

Don't. The `-1` in `px-1` is recognized as a negative number so incrementing it can only turn it into a `0`.

Instead, use `<C-x>` to decrement it to `-2` or follow this suggestion, found a few screens below `:help ctrl-a`:

```
For decimals a leading negative sign is considered for incrementing/
decrementing, for binary, octal and hex values, it won't be considered.  To
ignore the sign Visually select the number before using CTRL-A or CTRL-X.
```

Answer (score 0):

`vim` sees `px-1` as `px` and `-1`. To make it `-2` you don't want to increment it (-1 + 1 = 0), you want to decrement (-1 - 1 = -2).

The command to decrement is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>: [docs](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#CTRL-X).